# How to get rid of the "Edit links" link in the top navigation (SharePoint 2013)?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, navigation

I have a top navigation on my home page which holds links to subsites. 
Only on the top navigation on the home page, it shows a link called "Edit links" at the end of the navigation. Upon clicking it, one can edit the links in the navigation. 

The thing is that I don't want this to be there, this "Edit links" option.

All subsites inherit this top navigation, yet the subsites do not show the "Edit links" link. What do I need to do in order to get rid of the "Edit links" option for the home page? 

Should I edit the master page of the home page? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but I was able to hide it by adding the following lines to the masterpage:

```
<style type="text/css">
#DeltaTopNavigation .ms-core-listMenu-root .ms-listMenu-editLink {display: none;}
</style>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

The reason there is an `Edit Links` hyperlink there is because you have the permission to do so, most likely by have the `Design` permission. If your users do not have that permission level access, they will not see the link.

Also, when creating a subsite, there is an option to display the subsite on the parent's horizontal navigation, you may deselect the option so that your subsite does not appear on the parent site.

If by all means, you must remove that even for people with `Design` or higher permissions, then you may implement the many suggested CSS. For my implementation, I would use:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #DeltaTopNavigation > .ms-navedit-editArea
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

`DeltaTopNavigation` is the ID belonging to the div holding all the links of the top horizontal navigation.

ms-navedit-editArea is the class used on a list item for any of the Edit links within a navigation.

The CSS does the following:
Look for the element with ID `DeltaTopNavigation`, then look for the child elements which contains a classname of `ms-navedit-editArea`, and remove from display.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.ms-listMenu-editLink
{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

The above stylesheet will hide the Edit Link from Menu.

Comment: Please provide detailed answer and if not applicable add few lines to explain the answer. I think there are already many answers given this , so please provide answers to many other questions that might need answers and help the community in positive way, welcome aboard!

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and easiest way I found to remove the edit links option was by adding the Script Editor web part, then placing this code in it:

```
<style>
 .ms-displayInlineBlock{
       display: none;
 }
</style>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Anon, I'm not sure that hiding all the elements with class "ms-displayInlineBlock" is accurate : there could be some others elements having this class. I think that targetting the right element by naming its parent is more accurate (see @balownee answer)

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.ms-listMenu-editLink
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
```